# Default phase in modsecurity rules?

Tags: syntax, firewall, mod-security

I run modsecurity2 on apache 2.4 server on a CentOS machine (WHM enabled). To whitelist msnbot, my hosting provider asked me to add the following rule

```
SecRule REMOTE_HOST "@endsWith .search.msn.com" "allow,nolog,id:5000003,msg:'msn bot'"
```

There was no explicit mentioning of the `phase`. (modsecurity processes rules in 5 phases). When phase is not mentioned, what will be the default phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>There is no "default" phase. If you forgot to add this action, the rule won't evaluated.</s>

As I see the mod_security2 inserts a `phase:2` action to the rule, if there is no phase given.

Comment: But when I change nolog to log, the requests are getting logged....

Comment: Ah, I really sorry, my answer above was wrong. As I see it evaluated in phase 2 in case of mod_security2, but in phase 1 in libmodsecurity3. May be we can call this as "default"... You can check the phase with this: `grep -n "\(Starting phase\|5000003\)" /path/to/modsec_debug.log`. In the output of this command, you can see the "modified" rule: the engine appended an implicit `phase:2`: `Rule 7f18e894eaf0: SecRule "REMOTE_HOST" "@endsWith .search.msn.com" "phase:2,auditlog,allow,log,id:5000003,msg:'msn bot'"`. Sorry again.

Comment: No problem :). Thanks a lot. In addition to helping me find the answer, you also have explained the steps (grep on debug log) you used to find the implied phase This will help me in analyzing the functioning of modsecurity in detail in future as well.

Comment: Please can you help me with a doubt. In case I want to execute the rule "SecRule REMOTE_HOST "@endsWith .search.msn.com" "allow,nolog,id:5000003,msg:'msn bot'" in phase 1 instead of phase 2, is mentioning "phase 1" in the ACTIONS part of the rule will be sufficient? Or is that REMOTE_HOST based rules can only be executed in phase 2?

Comment: I think the explicit is always better than implicit :). You should put the `phase:1` to the actions list, and that will be enough. Generally, it is worth striving to put the rule to the lower phase, when the used variable available. REMOTE_HOST available in `phase:1`, this is a good choice for it.